# pivot_longer failing to transform to rows, instead keeping columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Using data from the following link:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv

I am trying to lengthen the data by collapsing all the dates into one date column. I renamed the data covid_confirmed_cases and have been using the following code:

```
long_confirmed_cases <- covid_confirmed_cases%>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(1/22/20:5/10/22), names_to = "date", values_to = "cases")

long_confirmed_cases
```

with no luck. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. The output keeps the dates in columns, but renames the columns as V1, V2 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are non-specific column names (as it starts with digits), so it can be backquoted.  Also, the last column name is `5/11/20` (`5/10/22` - assuming it is  month/day/year, would be two years from now)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
out <- covid_confirmed_cases%>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = c(`1/22/20`:`5/11/20`), 
     names_to = "date", values_to = "cases")
out %>%
   slice(1500:1510)
# A tibble: 11 x 6
#   `Province/State` `Country/Region`   Lat  Long date    cases
#   <chr>            <chr>            <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <int>
# 1 Tasmania         Australia        -41.5  146. 3/18/20    10
# 2 Tasmania         Australia        -41.5  146. 3/19/20    10
# 3 Tasmania         Australia        -41.5  146. 3/20/20    10
# 4 Tasmania         Australia        -41.5  146. 3/21/20    16
# 5 Tasmania         Australia        -41.5  146. 3/22/20    22
# 6 Tasmania         Australia        -41.5  146. 3/23/20    28
# 7 Tasmania         Australia        -41.5  146. 3/24/20    28
# 8 Tasmania         Australia        -41.5  146. 3/25/20    36
# 9 Tasmania         Australia        -41.5  146. 3/26/20    47
#10 Tasmania         Australia        -41.5  146. 3/27/20    47
#11 Tasmania         Australia        -41.5  146. 3/28/20    62
```

NOTE: Here, we are assuming that the OP read the dataset with `check.names = FALSE` if it is read with `read.csv/read.table`)

---

We can also use `matches`

```
covid_confirmed_cases%>% 
     pivot_longer(cols = matches("^\\d+/\\d+/\\d+$"), 
        names_to = "date", values_to = "cases")
```

Or with column index

```
covid_confirmed_cases%>% 
     pivot_longer(cols = 4:ncol(.), 
        names_to = "date", values_to = "cases")
```

#### data

```
covid_confirmed_cases <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, check.names = FALSE)
```